# Encryption using Different Ciphers and Modes

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

I've been asked by my univesity to perform the following code and provide 3 different encryption/decryption however for some reason the code provided doesn't work, I have found the same document multiple times and can't see much change from 2014.

Can someone please assist, full code below :

````
$ openssl enc -ciphertype -e -in plain.txt -out cipher.bin \
-K 00112233445566778889aabbccddeeff \
-iv 0102030405060708 ```

Please replace the ciphertype with a specific cipher type, such as -aes-128-cbc, -bf-cbc,
-aes-128-cfb, etc. In this task, you should try at least 3 different ciphers. You can find the meaning
of the command-line options and all the supported cipher types by typing "man enc". We include some
common options for the openssl enc command in the following:
```-in <file> input file
-out <file> output file
-e encrypt
-d decrypt
-K/-iv key/iv in hex is the next argument
-[pP] print the iv/key (then exit if -P)```

that's all that's been provided, i am using Seedlabs and Oracle VM Virtual box with SEEDUbuntu provided from Seedlabs.

I am in the right folder with the correct files available for encryption.

I've tried : -aes-128-cbc -e -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.bin \
-K 00112233445566778889aabbccddeeff \
-iv 0102030405060708
````

Comment: Did you type "man enc"?  Did you have any problems with what it said?